# Unlink a file from the CopySource in javascript

Tags: javascript, soap, copy-item

I'm using SOAP to copy files between Document Libraries, the issue is that after copying the item it gets linked to the source item and that is visible in the element properties. Manual unlinking does work for each element but I'm not aware of a javascript solution for this.

I know that `_CopySource` is responsible for that but the field seems to be read-only. Is there a method to reset `_CopySource` or unlink the file in javascript?

C# apparently had or has `fileToUnlink.UnlinkFromCopySource();`, but i can't find an equivalent in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, the `UnlinkFromCopySource` method of the `SPListItem` class is available neither via the `CSOM` nor via the `REST` interface. That means, it is probably not accessible from your `JavaScript` code, unless you create a custom wrapper web service for this method.

Some useful information about creating custom `SharePoint` web services is available [here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010/) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx).

Comment: I guess this is the only possible solution i have to reset `_CopySource` then. Thank you for the answer.